# Setting multidimentional arrays as vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have "int array[10][10]" (Two dimentional (Size can be changed!) ) 
and I want to set all of items into "vector> Vector"

I tried:

```
vector<vector<int>> Vector;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    Vector[i][j] = array[i][j];
}
```

But it doesnt work. I get this exception:

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Comment: did you resize vector ?

Comment: @mohaned I did not do any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<vector<int>> Vector(10, vector<int>(10));
```

will do the trick

Comment: @Tarik `operator[]` is unsafe in the sense that unlike `at()` it doesn't do any bounds checking. If you attempt to access an index that's greater than the container's size, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @remyabel: I have never seen a good use case for `at()`. An illegal vector index is always a programming error, and in C++ you do not want to throw exceptions for programming errors. It is also wrong to outright claim that `operator[]` does not do any bounds checking. Even though the standard does not require it, a good implementation will assert a correct index and terminate the program if the assertion fails. This is what likely happened in the OP's case.